# How to Select Data Within a multiple Price Range of Values with SQL BETWEEN Operator in Codeginter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, between

Price range filter.

**EX:> ( 0 to 10 and 15 to 20 and 60 to 100)**

```
$this->db->where('sales'  >= 0)

$this->db->where('sales'  <= 10)

$this->db->where('sales'  >= 15)

$this->db->where('sales'  <= 20)
```

.....etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are asking about group functions

```
$this->db->group_start();
  $this->db->where('sales >= ',  0);
  $this->db->where('sales <=',  10);
$this->db->group_end();
$this->db->or_group_start();
  $this->db->where('sales >=',  15);
  $this->db->where('sales <=',  20);
$this->db->group_end();
```

will produce

```
(`sales` >= 0 and `sales` <= 10) or (`sales` >= 15 and `sales` <= 20)
```

Comment: Thanks very very much @splash58

Answer (score 0):

Use this where condition.

```
$this->db->where('(sales  >= 0 AND <= 10) OR (sales  >= 15 AND <= 20) OR (sales  >= 60 AND <= 100)',NULL, FALSE );
```

Comment: Not use OR.  I want need multiple between. i like AND

Comment: @R.Surya `sales` can't be between 0 and 10  **AND** between 15 and 20 in the same time